# HighCharts (jQuery Pie Chart) is not getting rendered in IE

Tags: jquery, highcharts

My HighCharts pie chart is not getting rendered only in IE, It is rendering correctly in Chrome, FF, Opera and safari. But the issue is with my IE9. I have read the posts in stackoverflow and i corrected my code accordingly even though I got no luck.
Below is my sample .js code

```
$(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Build the chart
        $('#Chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text:'Time-Off Request'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 2

            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true

                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Time-Off Request Details',
                data: [
                    ['Vacation', 45.0],
                    ['Time-Off', 26.8],
                    ['Sick Time',12.8],
                    ['Personal', 8.5],
                    ['Bereavement', 6.2],
                    ['Others', 0.7]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Here is my Html div where i am trying to render my Pie Chart

```
<div id="Chart">
</div>
```

Can someone point me where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reproduced your example in jsfiddle and all works properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/z3fZv/
http://jsfiddle.net/z3fZv/show

```
$(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Build the chart
        $('#Chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text:'Time-Off Request'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 2

            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true

                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Time-Off Request Details',
                data: [
                    ['Vacation', 45.0],
                    ['Time-Off', 26.8],
                    ['Sick Time',12.8],
                    ['Personal', 8.5],
                    ['Bereavement', 6.2],
                    ['Others', 0.7]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Have you the newest highcharts release ?